# Need approach for screen development in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I need expertise advice/approach for starting screen development in android.
I got a couple of screens from my customer and i need to develop them.
I went through lot of tutorials and understood about supporting multiple resolutions and sizes all that is fine, but i want to understand basic things like how to properly place the UI elements. Should we need to use any tools like photoshop for measuring units like top bottom right left etc and place the UI element in xml or just by approxiamtion we will place the UI element.

For example consider this screen https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/137442/screenshots/1234960/attachments/166804/Login-screen.png.

for ex How you will place the user name and password edit texts. I mean how much of top left bottom margins will be used. is that just approximation or need to be measured using tools like photoshop.
Say i used photoshop and got the values in pixes if i convert them to dp and use those values in layout will they support for other screen sizes??

are there any tools which can take the screen iamge which i posted above as an input and generate the android layout from it.

Comment: Depends, if you don't have much time you could do it approx.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Photoshop to measure the units. The Android SDK has several layouts with their accompanying properties and options that will allow you to pretty much achieve any UI implementation. imho there are not tools that will 'take a screen image and generate the android layout from it'.

Comment: No my question is how i will come to know where to place a button in the layout for ex in the above link login button. is it just by approximation like 30dp margin bottom and 10dp right & left margin ?

Comment: right and left? you dont need those, just "center in parent horizontally", read about the android layouts starting with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html